.Net 8 file upload limits. Trying to upload an 89MB file to my API controller
For smaller files (i.e. 30MB or so) I have no issues. However, once I attempt to upload an 89MB file to my API Controler it throws (Request Entity Too Large) errors:
From my front end:
POST http://localhost:21971/api/import/MediaUpload?sessionID=***&pid=*** net::ERR_FAILED 413 (Request Entity Too Large)

My backend .Net 8 API project contains an import.controller.cs:


[HttpPost]
 [Route("MediaUpload")]
 public async Task<IActionResult> MediaUpload([FromQuery] string sessionId, [FromQuery] string pid, [FromForm] ImportMediaUploadModel formData)
{
  IFormCollection form;

  try
  {
      form = await Request.ReadFormAsync();
      form.Keys.ToList().ForEach(key =>
      {
          if (key.Equals("MediaInfo", StringComparison.InvariantCultureIgnoreCase))
          {
              formData.MediaInfo = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<List<MediaInfo>>(form[key]);
          }
      });
  }
  
     for (var i = 0; i < formData.Files?.Count; i++)
   {
       UploadFile(formData.Files[i]);
   }   
   // ...
   return Ok();
 } 
  
   private async void UploadFile(IFormFile file)
  {
      var thisFileName = file.FileName.Trim('\"');
      string? localPath = config[key: "ImportImageFolderPath"];
      string fullPath = Path.Combine(localPath, thisFileName);
      FileInfo fileInfo = new(fullPath);

      using var stream = System.IO.File.Create(fullPath);
      await file.CopyToAsync(stream);
  }



I'm getting this same error uploading in the QA environment (and not just at localhost).

I am reading thru some docs such as this, https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/mvc/models/file-uploads?view=aspnetcore-8.0, but I lack some expertise-level knowledge in latest .Net.
Thanks in advance for any advice on how to deal with file upload limitations in .Net 8.
In our html template, the two relevant parts are here:


<input
    multiple
    #fileInputElement
    type="file"
    style="display:none;"
    (change)="loadImagesFromInput($event)"
    accept=".jpg, .tiff, .png, .gif, .bmp, .pdf, .avi, .wmv, .mp4, .mpg, .mpeg, .mov, .3gp, .3g2, .m4v, .fda"
  />

  <button mat-flat-button color="primary" (click)="openFileBrowser()" title="Add Images" i18n-title="@@addImages">
    <mat-icon svgIcon="add"></mat-icon>
    <span i18n="@@addImages">Add Images</span>
  </button>
  <span class="spacer"></span>
  <button mat-flat-button color="primary" [disabled]="isSaveButtonDisabled()" (click)="save()" title="Save"
    i18n-title="@@save">
    <mat-icon svgIcon="save-to-disk"></mat-icon>
    <span i18n="Button|Generic label for save option@@save">Save</span>
  </button>
  
  



and our typescript:


save(): void {
  this.isLoading = true;
  const sessId = this.appSession.session.SessionID;
  const params = { pID: this.selectedPat.PID };

  // Populate MediaInfo object (some conversions to match the server model)
  const mediaInfo: MediaInfo[] = this.importImages.map((image) => {
      return {
          PID: this.selectedPat.PID,
          /// add'l fields removed for brevity..
      };
  });

  const submitFormData = () => {
      const formData = new FormData();
      formData.append('MediaInfo', JSON.stringify(mediaInfo));
      formData.append('CsiXmlFolder', this.csiXmlFolder);
      for (let i = 0; i < this.importImages.length; i++) {
          if (this.importImages[i].image.date !== '' && this.importImages[i].image.date !== undefined) {
              this.importImages[i].image.date = formatDate(this.importImages[i].image.date, 'shortDate', 'en-US');
          }
      }

      for (const image of this.importImages) {
          formData.append('files', this.dataURItoBlob(image.image.TnUrl), image.image.name);
      }         

      const captureEndpoint = this.selectedDeviceObj.Url;            

      this.importService.saveImportObjects(formData, params, captureEndpoint).subscribe({
          next: (data) => {
    // toast msg, etc.
          },

      });
  };
  
  saveImportObjects(formData: FormData, params, endpointUri: string): Observable<HttpClient> {
    // NOTE: multipart and boundary header added by browser automatically.

    let url = '';
    let pid = '';       

    endpointUri = "http://localhost:21971/api/import/MediaUpload?"; // ** LOCAL DEV TESTING **
    
    if (endpointUri !== null) {
        url = `${endpointUri}sessID=${this.appSession.getSess()}&pId=${pid}`;
    }

    return this.http.post<any>(url, formData);
  }




just a security note: You should avoid doing this: var thisFileName = file.FileName.Trim('"'); and then using that to create the file.  Never trust user input.  You should be in full control of the filename and extension used when you save the file to your server.  (cases/switch extension if you have to... allow only certain cases.. use a fallback extension if you have no case for it)

It's also a little easier to just create a class with all the fields you need... one of them being IFormFile, and then [bind] that to the POST.  (instead of mixing get-like query params, and POST, and then getting raw request, iterating form fields, deserializing etc... .net's binding will do all the work for you )

it's a bit over-complicated on the front-end.  You should just get the form and create FormData from that... ex:  let form = document.getElementById('YourFormsID')! as HTMLFormElement;
let formData = new FormData(form);  Then let ASP.NET bind to the form.  Right now it looks like you are creating a client-side copy, then sending that... (twice? as mediaInfo and then as files?)  The fields can all bind to their names, the file(s) can bind to Listex: [BindProperty]
public List fileInputElement { get; set; }  (you'll bind on the 'name' attribute)

You could use [RequestSizeLimit(500*1024*1024)] attribute to handle requests up to 500 MB.
[HttpPost]
[Route("MediaUpload")]
[RequestSizeLimit(500*1024*1024)]
public async Task<IActionResult> MediaUpload([FromQuery] string sessionId, [FromQuery] string pid, [FromForm] ImportMediaUploadModel formData)
{

Or you can configure in Program.cs like below:
builder.Services.Configure<FormOptions>(x => {
    //x.ValueCountLimit = int.MaxValue;
    x.MultipartBodyLengthLimit = long.MaxValue;
});

The third way is to add the web.config file and use [DisableRequestSizeLimit] attribute, refer to this answer.

the RequestSizeLimit doesn't seem to work at the controller level. My file is 89MB, and it still throws the "Too Large" error on front end. I never even hit my backend breakpoint (which always works for my small 30MB file uploads). I'll try the builder injection idea ..

not working at the program.cs layer either with builder.Services config - FormOptions nor IISServerOptions. For those larger files it just stops at the browser; never hits my backend vs2022 instance running on localhost.

you should probably include your front-end code in your question along with code for ImportMediaUploadModel class.

Hi @bob.mazzo, as browsematoer said, pls share your frontend code.

Hi @browsermator I have posted the two relevant frontend ts methods, thank you.

at the IIS level, we needed to deal with the "Request Filter" option within the website. I could be done in the web.config. It's all in this post https://www.inflectra.com/Support/KnowledgeBase/KB306.aspx .

As a side note, nothing I did at the C# API layer would let the larger then 30MB through on my local.

IIS configuration needed to increase the max file size: https://www.inflectra.com/Support/KnowledgeBase/KB306.aspx.
In the web.config:
<system.webServer>
  <security>
    <requestFiltering>
      <requestLimits maxAllowedContentLength="2147483648" />
      </requestFiltering>
   </security>
 </system.webServer>

or
Directly in IIS settings -  edit Requests Filtering.
The answer above by @Rena also contains the following link re: web.config How to increase or set the upload media file size unlimited in ASP.NET Core 2.2 project

It seems the same as what i shared in the link of the third way. So is this the solution?

@Rena - I was too focused on the C# API part, and probably missed the web.config piece. In addition, I had understood that we could NOT use web.config any longer in our .Net 8 project (rather only appsettings.json); but I didn't realize that when we publish/build the projects - a web.config is indeed created.
